# How can I show formValidation from a nestend Blazor EditForm

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-server-side

Say I have a Person class which can have a list of addresses. I want to create a blazor EditForm where the user fills the required information for the person and hit a button to add one ore multiple address elements.If they add an address field, form validation should pick up that its not allowed to have an empty street value.

The problem is that it seems like the automatic validation from Edit form just ignores the inner component all together.

```cs
public class Person
{
    [Required]
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Age {get;set;

    public List<Address> Addresses {get;set;}
}

public class Address
{
    [Required]
    public string Street {get;set;}
}
```

CreatePerson form

```cs
<div>
    <EditForm Model="person" OnValidSubmit="CreateNewPerson">
        <DataAnnotationsValidator />

        <div>
            <label for="name">Name</label>
            <InputText class="" id="name" @bind-Value="person.Name" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="age">Age</label>
            <InputNumber id="age" @bind-Value="person.Age" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <label>Addresses</label>
            <AddressEditor Addresses="person.Addresses" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit">Create</button>
        </div>
                
        <ValidationSummary />
    </EditForm>
</div>


@code{
    private Person person = new();
    
    private async Task CreateNewPerson()
    {
     // ... logic for submitting
    }
}
```

AddressEditor

```cs
<div>
    <button type="button" @onclick="AddNewAddress">Add</button>
</div>

@for (var i = 0; i < Addresses.Count; i++)
{
    <EditForm Model=Addresses[i]">
        <div>
            <label>Street</label>
            <InputText @bind-Value="Addresses[i].Street"/>
        </div>
    </EditForm>
}


@code{
    [Parameter}
    private List<Address> Addresses = new();
    
    private void AddNewAddress()
    {
         Addresses.Add(new Address());
    }
}
```

I have tried passing a EditContext in to the inner component, but it didnt seem to have any effect, I also tried to add "DataAnnotationsValidator" in the inner component but that only duplicated the error message i get from the missing Person name (if it was missing)

Comment: DataAnnotationsValidator does not support complex/nested objects.  Check out - https://github.com/mrpmorris/blazor-validation and https://github.com/Blazored/FluentValidation

Answer (score 1):

I've ran into this limitiation of DataAnnotations a few years ago. I'm not sure if there is any other way right now but what I did back in 2020 was using the preview version of this package
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.DataAnnotations.Validation/3.2.0-rc1.20223.4 from Microsoft. It hasen't been updated since then but I can confirm it still works with .NET 7.

The key to this is to add this attribute to your list.

```cs
[ValidateComplexType]
public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
```

Personally I would use FluentValidation for more complex validation since it offers much more possibilities then DataAnnotations.